# React-Admin: `make` commands are failing

Tags: node.js, windows, makefile, react-admin

I'm trying to get my local environment working after cloning the `react-admin` repo.
I'm tried to run `make install` and `make build` as guided by the docs, but these won't work for me.

I install `make` globally. And `yarn`, `npm` and `nodejs` are all up-to-date.
 I'm on `Windows-10` using Visual Studio Code with `PowerShell` terminal.
This is what I get...

> `make install` returns:

```sh
make i info Invoking install target
(node:7316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:7316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7316) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make × ERR  not found: make-package.json
```

> `make build` returns:

```sh
(node:9000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:9000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9000) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make × ERR  not found: make-##
```

> I really want to get started on my `ra fix branch` so any help would be appreciated.
> Hopefully, it's just a simple mistake on my end.

Comment: These seem to be errors from whatever command make is invoking.  They don't appear to be problems with make itself.

Comment: This is my first time using make. The last line in "make install" says it couldn't find make-package.json but the file in the repo is makefile. Why isn't it going after the makefile?

make install is just installing package via yarn: `install: package.json 
 @yarn`

Comment: Could the windows version of make have some syntax differences regarding its usage and makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to note that `make` is primarily a utility tool for the `unix` env.
Therefore running `make` commands is not a direct process in `windows` environment.

> [NMAKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) is the official windows alternative that will help you achieve the same.

Comment: Seems make is included in Visual Studio Code so I don't think that's my issue. Seems like a specific problem with React Admin's codebase or my local environment. Hoping RA staff could chime in here...

You can find the repo/docs here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin

Comment: Well, you can install any `extensions` to VSC. But think about it critically and let's ask ourselves - If I add a `nodejs` extension to VSC, without installing `nodejs` on `windows`, would i expect any `node commands` to work? Definitely not. Bottom line you need to install `make` for unix, or `nmake` the windows alternative. [Here's a good read](https://www.40tude.fr/blog/compile-cpp-code-with-vscode-cmake-nmake/) from this windows-10 user (note, they working with `make` alternatives (even though not directly using `react-admin`).